# Can you see yourself in space?

Tags: visible-light, astronomy, space

Can one see them self in space if no near by star was in view? Is there enough star light to read once your eyes adjust?

Comment: To a very good estimate, isn't this basically the same as asking if you can read by starlight if you are alone in, say, a large desert on a clear, moonless night?

Comment: I've been to dark sky locations for astronomy. Even without the moon, you can see enough to get around, see the equipment and see people around you. The sky is amazing to see. Every part of the sky seems to have a star. It gets confusing when you are trying to pick out constellations. You would need pretty large print to read.

Comment: @PeterR - interesting comment - I am wondering how much if any of that 'background' light be scattered from the sun? -- and is the background light an issue for the astronomical measurements? (sorry guess these could be two question here on their own....)

Comment: The sun is not a factor. There is sky glow in the darkest areas but that is relatively weak as compared to the light from the stars and Milky Way. Usually, light pollution from nearby cities is the biggest problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

If you go to a random spot in the visible universe, you will usually be far from any galaxies because the separation between galaxies is large compared to the size of the galaxies themselves.

Since distant galaxies are so dim that we can't even see them, you certainly cannot see your reflection by them.